# Seg fault with time and ctime, when porting from Linux to OSX

Tags: c, time, segmentation-fault, ctime

I am getting errors compiling code designed for (I believe) Linux on OSX. I have tracked down the issue to this section of code:

```
TIMEVAL = time(NULL);
char* TIMESTRING = ctime(&TIMEVAL);
TIMESTRING[24]=' ';

fprintf(LOG, "[ %20s] ", TIMESTRING);
```

Is there any reason why this might be the case? I have included `<time.h>`.

Comment: Since you are getting a segmentation fault, check whether `TIMESTRING[24]` is valid or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ctime` is using a statically allocated buffer of a certain size, so your first problem is that you're appending to that string without knowing the size.

```
TIMESTRING[24]=' ';
```

This might cause a segfault on it's own if the buffer is only 24 bytes. Another cause might be if the zero-termination happens to be at index 24, you just made the string unterminated, and `fprintf` will continue reading until it hits memory it's not allowed to read, resulting in the segfault.

Use `ctime_r` with a preallocated buffer if you want to modify it, and make sure the buffer is large enough to hold your data, and is zero-terminated after you're done with it. If `ctime_r` isn't available, do a `strncpy` to your own buffer before modifying.

HTH

**EDIT**

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but assuming the code you posted is taken directly from your application, you're probably actually looking to do this:

```
TIMEVAL = time(NULL);
char* TIMESTRING = ctime(&TIMEVAL);

fprintf(LOG, "[ %20s ] ", TIMESTRING);
```

That is, pad your time string. Just add the space in your formatting string instead of in the time-string buffer.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. That did the trick nicely, and I now understand what they were trying to do in the first place...

Comment: I'm now getting some warnings, but they seem to be from the ctime/time calls themselves. I've posted a separate question about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041374/ctime-and-time-warnings-compiling-on-osx

Answer (score 1):

Taking this as an example what ctime returns - **Sat May 20 15:21:51 2010** which is only 24 characters ( i.e., 24 bytes ). So, you array index start from **0 to 23**. So, at index 24 it has termination character.

So, `TIMESTRING[24]=' ';` is **wrong** ( i.e., you are replacing the termination character with a space character ) and is causing you the segmentation fault at later stages.

Comment: Actually, the null-termination is at index 24, causing the string to be unterminated. `fread` will then trigger the fault. The write itself is not causing it.

Comment: @roe - Yes, we have access to termination character but it shouldn't be modified. Isn't it correct ?

Comment: you're correct that it is wrong to do so in this case, but "there is no index 24" is not correct. If you happen to know that the allocated buffer is larger than this, it's perfectly ok to add more characters, overwriting the null, just make sure you append a null at the end afterwards. Thing is you don't know for sure how large that buffer is, as it's an implementation detail of ctime and might vary. Also, you don't HAVE to have strings as null-terminated ones, if you know the length of the string. Most library functions assume they are though.

Comment: @roe - Thanks for the detailed explanation. Modified my answer description accordingly.