# ctime and time warnings compiling on OSX

Tags: c, time, warnings, ctime

I am getting some warnings when compiling a C program on OSX 10.6.5, which seem to be quite critical.

```
extras.c:15: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘time’
extras.c: In function ‘outlog’:
extras.c:363: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘ctime’
```

The corresponding lines are as follows:

Lines 13-15:

```
RANDNUMGEN = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_taus);
long t1;
(void) time(&t1);
```

Lines 360-363:

```
if (LOG==NULL) { LOG=stdout;}

TVAL = time(NULL);
char* TIMESTRING = ctime(&TVAL);
```

I believe the program was originally written for Linux, so I wonder if there is a difference between `time` and `ctime` on the two platforms?

Answer (score 3):

Verify that the C files contains:

```
#include <time.h>
```

somewhere around the top.

Also,

```
long t1;
time(t1);
```

is pretty lousy code, the argument to `time()` has type `time_t*`, so that should read

```
time_t t1;
time(&t1);
```